# Cannot retrieve object from inner dictionaries/lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am currently trying to get an object deeply nested within a dictionaries and lists.

The object is the ProductPrice object within the ProductInfo dictionaries.

The structure is:

[Debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW2Xf.png)

I have tried the following LINQ however this only returns me the list (right before the object)

```
                       var Lis = productInfo
                            .Where(x => x.Key == "Prices")
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
                            .Where(x => x.Key == "Prices")
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                            .ToList()
                            .First();
```

The productinfo class is a dictionary which is of the type <string, object>. I dont know why the first() command still gives me the full list and not the object itself... any ideas of how to iterate the first dictionary find the prices dictionary then iterate that one. Retrieve the list and finally get the first element of it?

The result of my linq is her:

[Linq variable first()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIK4Q.png)

Update Product Info Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dynamicweb.Ecommerce.Integration
{
    public class ProductInfo : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public ProductInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are going to have to show the declaration of all the containers here. productInfo is a list of what? If those objects have other classes in them we need to see the definitions of those too, in text, not screen shots

Comment: I have attached the ProductInfo class definition. My question is rather "why do the Lis variable contain a list and not the first element? which is ProductPrice"

Comment: Is SelectMany is what you are looking for instead of Select? Select is selecting the List object. SelectMany would select the values of the List object. Also ToList is unnecessary and will force enumeration over the entire collection (consider OfType if you are using that for casting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate anything. Your `productInfo` is a dictionary of objects. You need to cast the value of the dictionary access to the appropriate type (`List<ProductPrice>`) and operate on that. In this case, you can call `First()` to get the first item in the list.

```
var query = ((List<ProductPrice>)productInfo["Prices"]).First();
```

If it's possible to not have "Prices` in the dictionary or it's not in an expected type or potentially empty, you can check for that.

```
var query = productInfo.TryGetValue("Prices", out var v) && v is IEnumerable<ProductPrice> e
    ? e.FirstOrDefault()
    : default;
```

Comment: Would it not be more efficient to instead do: `var query = ((IEnumerable<ProductPrice>)productInfo["Prices"]).ElementAt(0);`?

Comment: Not necessarily. The cast would be the same either way and the choice between `First()` and `ElementAt()` also wouldn't really matter. Since the underlying object is a list, they're effectively equivalent. If we were not getting the first item but at some other index other than the last, then `ElementAt()` might have been necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be sure and I cannot test this becuase I dont have you classes or data so I can only go off your debug screen shots

```
 var prices = productInfo["Prices"];
```

prices seems to be a `List` of something.something.ProductPrice. But it looks like you want the first one. So its just

```
 var prices = productInfo["Prices"].First();
```

I dont see why you need that hugely complex LINQ chain. Or are you truying to extarct someting from the ProductPrice class